# Room-specific welcome message for new users

Tags: feature-request, chat

Lots of the bigger channels have some kind of rules, stuff people are supposed to read before posting or requesting access, etc.

In the topic it clutters valuable space that can be used for more useful things (regulars usually don't need a link about when to request access etc. there).
When a bot pings newly joining user with the message it's even more annoying since it gets pretty spammy for everyone in there.

So my suggestion is to allow room owners to define a welcome message for their room. It could contain markdown (either true markdown or like normal chat messages) and would be shown to a user who has never talked in the room and hasn't been in the room ever or at least for some time (1 month maybe).

Possibly users should be required to click a "confirm" button to be able to talk - otherwise they'll most likely just ignore it without even bothering to read it (yes, I'm talking to you, help vampires)

Comment: well not only to new also to regular user ... i mean when user enters in chat room every time it ping and shows that message .. now blame to Jerk :P

Comment: well, that's most likely a bug in the JS room bot

Comment: You can always put a shortened link into the room topic

Comment: Because people totally read it (besides that, see my post why the topic is not the optimal place)

Comment: If only this hadn't been posted on April 1st :P

Comment: Update: the current mobile UI doesn't display the room topic once you've entered the room, so putting a link to the rules there is even less effective than previously.

Answer (score 11):

I like this idea, could really be used in the [Python](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) room, where much like other rooms is constantly attracting questions from new users who usually start with the too oft-repeated phrase "Can I ask something?"

I would suggest that if (hopefully when) such a feature will be added, that it also include more customization beyond just the message (even with its markdown) such that a room owner could define some rules for it.

For instance, maybe multiple messages, with different parameters, the parameters could include things like:

- "show to new users": only the first time a user enters the channel he gets the message.
- "show to all users": show this message for every user that logs into the channel.
- "show to owners": will only show to room owners (useful to give important information for rooms with multiple owners,
- "show to group": allow a selection of users to be a group that will receive this message ([use case](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/8714722#8714722)).
- "reset": would be a timer that resets the message for users, so if the message has a timer of 1 month, and is set to display only to new users, every user will be reverted to having not seen the message after 1 month, and will get it again.

These are just some ideas, which I think would add to this feature.

Answer (score 3):

> Possibly users should be required to click a "confirm" button to be able to talk - otherwise they'll most likely just ignore it without even bothering to read it (yes, I'm talking to you, help vampires)

This doesn't change just because you add a "confirm" button step.

The current permstar approach works just fine. It's actually *better*, as the rules are then persistent and even regulars may refer to them from time to time with ease.