# Allow room owners to customize the welcome pop up

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

Today, a welcome pop up was rolled out to users in chat:

[image]

This is useful, but I feel as though it would be even more useful if room owners could use it to specify what was and wasn't allowed in their room. Encouraging users to flag something just because it makes them feel "uneasy" is going to greatly increase the number of out-of-context flags, leading to decisions being made by mods and 10k users from all over the site, who have no idea of the atmosphere of the room, and no context with which to make their decision on the flag.

Furthermore, this could be another tool to help with keeping rooms in line, by giving the room owner an ability to force the message to pop up for everyone currently in the room, reminding them of the rules.

As much as people might wish it were so, not every room has the same idea of what is acceptable and what is not, and I think that trying to treat them as if they do is just going to lead to problems.

Comment: Re: flags - is this actually a problem?

Comment: We've definitely had issues before. It doesn't happen terribly often, but it's very frustrating when it does.

Comment: [Similar suggestion from a few years back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174533/room-specific-welcome-message-for-new-users)

Comment: flaggers won't even see this pop up in most cases, they don't have to visit the room to validate a flag. The pop up is also shown only once per account so far, not per room

Comment: Can you re-summon this pop-up once it's dismissed? I can't see how, and that seems like it makes a pretty bad place for additional rules to be inserted. Couldn't you just put them in the chat room description itself?

Comment: @MadScientist The popup was more aimed at people doing the flagging rather than those validating flags. And yes, it would have to be changed to a per-room basis.

Answer (score 13):

This is an attempt to establish some groundrules for *all of chat*, based on [previous discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270587/toward-a-philosophy-of-chat) and [bluefeet's chat moderation wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat). Notably, the "flag it" guidance *links to the latter*, which attempts to explain the use of flagging with a bit more nuance.

This will appear only once per user - its goal is to *introduce* people to the idea of chat as a moderated space, not provide a reference or constantly nag them.

If you find yourself, as a room owner, needing to remind people of the rules specific to your room, I recommend reading [the moderation guide for room owners](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat/271269#271269) - specifically the portion that explains how to use a descriptive room description along with kick-muting to present the room's topic to the confused.

> Furthermore, this could be another tool to help with keeping rooms in line, by giving the room owner an ability to force the message to pop up for everyone currently in the room, reminding them of the rules.

This is roughly identical to the "timeout" feature, which is currently available only to moderators. A proposal to make this function available to room owners would be a reasonable means of accomplishing your goal here.

Comment: Alright, good to know. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Because the request is based on a rather severe misunderstanding of what the pop-up does, and I'd rather correct that quickly so as to encourage more productive requests than let everyone waste time on a dead-end, @davidism. Based on the *needs* that Saint is describing, expanding availability of the "timeout" feature OR something like [a per-room FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233692/one-page-wikis-to-store-all-the-chat-rooms-nuggets-and-references) would be more appropriate.

Comment: That was more what I was looking for. I realize I forgot to put that in the question, but I was suggesting for room owners to be able to expand upon the text of the pop-up, not replace it. I will admit that I had not understood how limited the current popup is when I asked the question.

Comment: What's the point of customizing a pop-up that a majority of people will *never see again*, @davidism? If someone's first chatroom is the result of "continue this discussion in chat", they're never gonna see what you put there. That's the entire function of this pop-up: to appear once, to everyone, and then go away. You want a pop-up that contains different text, appears at a different time, and in total behaves completely differently - so just ask for that instead of trying to piggyback on a completely unrelated thing.

Comment: @Shog9 So if I changed the question to be suggesting an entirely separate popup, would it go back into consideration? I feel as though the type of popup I'm suggesting would entirely supplant the current one, which is why I suggested it as a modification to the current popup, but if that's not an option, I can suggest that instead.

Comment: Unless the problem you're trying to solve involves communicating something to every new user upon their first experience with chat, it's very unlikely the solution will have much overlap with this popup. So... Why don't you start with the problem you're trying to solve, @SaintWacko? Write a post that lays it out, and then proposes a solution to it. [Here's an entirely-too-long essay that you should read](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta/272617#272617)