# Typo in chat pop-up

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, wording

Not of any major consequence, but there is a small typo in the new chat pop-up reminding everyone to Be Nice, as the image below indicates:

[image]

"Keep these mind" needs to be changed to "Keep these in mind".

Comment: I didn't take a screenshot when I saw it (and I think you see it only once), so the image is taken from [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276567/267616). And history of how this post came about, can be seen [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28080113#28080113).

Comment: Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Keepthesemind Haha. I thought it might have been a reference to your username when I saw the circled part. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fixed. I added an in in in the file.